Should I wait for a confirmation to my confirmation to a proposed interview?
It has happened to me a few times that I get an e-mail for a job offer, respond with when they want to arrange an (online) meeting, they follow up. They want to meet (online), with a proposed date and time . I respond yes. I do not get any more information and nothing happens on that date and time. This has happened a few times in where it was scheduled for the following day... Nobody showed up (showed up nowhere because there was no meets nor teams invitation nor any message received, ever).
My point is that I scheduled to have some free time there to be available because I assumed I would get the call invitation at some point before the interview. But it does not arrive. Sometimes sending an e-mail results in being ghosted, sometimes they follow up with whatever. But it's me who initiates it to know what happened.
Should I not schedule my time for the interview unless I receive a confirmation of some sort (a call invitation). I feel it would look "impolite" for the interviewer if the invitation is sent 5 minutes before without any previous confirmation which results in me declining it. But I feel it's more impolite to not use 30 seconds to reply and either confirm or cancel.

If you want the job, assume they were just forgetful and call in/show up; at worst you've wasted a bit of effort and you won't pass up an opportunity.
Or ping them and say "Hey, did my confirmation  reach you?"
Or both.
If you really don't care about this application, or are sufficiently offended by their forgetting to respond that you are no longer interested, don't.
All of the above, some of the above, none of the above... Pick one you're comfortable with. You shouldn't need our opinions/advice to do so; your own decision is the one that matters.

I'm sorry this happened to you, but there is really nothing you can do about it.
Ideally, they should get back with either of below:

A confirmation of the meet-up at the time you proposed, with some sort of a meeting invite / link.
Request to reschedule, or alternate slots with a request to choose one of the available slots for them.

However, if they do not get back, then that indicates they do not want to proceed with the process (for whatever reason). Again, I'd say expect the invite or confirmation at least a day before the date of interview.
In case there is no communication, feel free to unblock your calendar to accommodate other engagement(s).
